# small page for answer

Tags: html, date, addition

I need to create a page where user can see answer after he picks a date, program add 2 months and show date. Right now it's working like "alert" i don't know how create  program which write answer under calendar

```
<body>
   
    <input type="date" name="date" id="date"
           onchange="var chooseDate = new Date(this.value);
    chooseDate.setDate(chooseDate.getUTCDate() + 60);
    var futureDate = chooseDate.getFullYear() + '-' + ('0' + (chooseDate.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + '-' + ('0' + (chooseDate.getDate())).slice(-2);
    alert('Dateadd ' + futureDate);" />

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

The  field has a property called **value**. You can write the output of your calculation to the value field to set the value seen in the date-field.

Check out the documentation of input:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date